# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object on a Collection

Tags: apex, nested

I have a nested Collection like this :

```
public class EntityReportsSearch {
        public Data_Contract.ArrayOfEntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria Entities;
        public String ReferenceID;
}

 public class ArrayOfEntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria {
        public Data_Contract.EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria[] EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria;
}

 public class EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria {
        public String EntityID;
        public String EntityIDType;
        public String ReferenceID;
}
```

I am populating this EntityReportsSearch object for a Soap call like this :

```
 Data_Contract.EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria entity = new Data_Contract.EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria();
        
entity.EntityID = '98765';
entity.EntityIDType = ‘ABC’;
entity.ReferenceID= 'ref01';


Data_Contract.ArrayOfEntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria entities  = new Data_Contract.ArrayOfEntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria();

entities.EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria.add(entity);
```

I am getting error on this line :  `entities.EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria.add(entity);`
In the debug log I can see `entities.EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria` is null but I am trying to add value to that empty collection.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new `ArrayOfEntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria`, it contains an uninitialized `Data_Contract.EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria[]`, which means that class variable is *null*.

A null/unititialized variable and an empty list are not the same. `null.<anything>` = a Null Pointer Exception.

To be able to add to a list, you need to initialize the class variable somehow. Either through

- a constructor
- changing the definition of `public Data_Contract.EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria[] EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria;` to set an initial value (e.g. `public Data_Contract.EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria[] EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria = new List<Data_Contact.EntityReports_EntitySearchCriteria>();`)
- Initializing the list in your code, sometime before trying to `add()` to the list

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can't add Constructor/change the definition but I am interested in the 3rd option : 
```Initializing the list in your code, sometime before trying to add() to the list```

How can I do that ?

Comment: @user3444999 you do a simple null check against the list and if the list is null, you set the list to `= new List<ObjectType>` prior to calling `list.add(record)`

Comment: Thank you @Darek/@Morgan - Worked well